# Can multiple game objects share properties? For example, a single quaternion that multiple objects use as their rotation value

Tags: unity-game-engine

Can multiple game objects share properties? For example, a single quaternion that multiple objects use as their rotation value. I basically want to have every objects's transform.rotation be a pointer to one quaternion so I can rotate them all without updating every object.

Comment: Since a Quaternion is a struct, you won't be able to store it by reference (if the property you're storing is a reference type variable though, that could work). What you could do is store a reference to a script that has a Quaternion rotation defined on it, then every frame (or every change to the reference rotation) update your rotation to match that rotation. Why don't you try something like that, then pose a question here if you get really stuck implementing it?

Comment: Currently I've got a script that calculates the rotation and then applies it to all objects. But that's a lot of transform.rotations being set to the same values every frame. It would be more efficient to have each transform.rotation be a pointer to a single quaternion, if such a thing were possible?

Comment: How about updating rotations only if the last rotation differs from the newly-calculated one? That should cut down significantly on unnecessary assignments, and won't require you to alter your program design.

Comment: Unfortunately that wouldn't offer any valuable improvement. Sometimes it'll be updating every frame, sometimes not for several seconds. But the frames when it does update will still take the performance hit. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: In the absence of something equivalent to pointers, I'll probably resort to time splicing it in a coroutine. In this particular context the lag shouldn't be too obvious to the user.

Comment: Usage of pointers in C# is rare and a lot more complicated than C++/other non-managed languages (you can only use them in an `unsafe` context, which has its own caveats). Generally you'd just be advised to make use of a reference type instead. Anyways, if you're trying to spread out a costly operation, a coroutine sounds fine - just remember that each iteration of a coroutine requires one `Update()` call - so if you have too many iterations, there could be a visual delay in the rotation update.

Comment: I don't know if this is a viable option, but you could [set a rotation matrix](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetMatrix.html) on a material that way every object that has that material will rotate.

Comment: That's a brilliant idea! Thank you Pluto. I hadn't even heard of that. I'll profile both solutions just to make sure that one's faster, but it seems like it should be.

Comment: Ah, reading the docs more thoroughly, I see that it only rotates the UVs, not the actual geometry.

Comment: You can use the matrix to rotate vertices not just uvs ex: `o.vertex = mul(_RotationMatrix, v.vertex);`

Answer (score 0):

No they can't share the properties but you could make a singleton so you only process the data once and assigns it in the update from the others scripts/objects.

If I were you I would create a Singleton with the modifications to the Quaterion,and with a public access to the Quaterion,  you could access from any script.

So in that way in your update you will have just to set the rotation to the singleton value.

If you need more help let me know.